# Calling super().method() in a subclass that does not override method

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, super, method-resolution-order

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) of `super` states:

> This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class.

Is there a point in calling `super().method()` in a subclass that does *not* override `method`?

To me there is not, since calling `self.method()` would be equivalent, that is to say inheritance would look `method` up in `self`'s superclasses using the same `type(self).__mro__` method resolution order (given by the [C3 linearization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) of `self`'s superclass hierarchy) than `super`.

So to me, `super` is useful in this situation:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        print("A")

class B:
    pass

class C(B, A):
    def f(self):
        super().f()
        print("C")

C().f()  # prints A C
```

but not in this one:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        print("A")

class B:
    pass

class C(B, A):
    def g(self):
        super().f()  # should be just self.f()
        print("C")

C().g()  # prints A C
```

Comment: It depends. Remember, in `C`, you *don't know* which class `super()` will refer to. That's determined at runtime, and `self` may be an instance of some descendent of `C` that you don't know about. *That* class might override `f`.

Comment: (Which is to say, your "useless" example is actually *worse* than useless, as it may actively prevent the correct method from being called in the first place.)

Comment: @chepner Yes with `super().f()` in `C` you don't know which class it will refer to, but neither with `self.f()`, do you?

Comment: But you aren't actively *skipping* an implementation with `self.f()`. You give `type(f).f` a chance to run, and let it decide if it needs to call a method it overrides.

Comment: @chepner I think you meant `type(self).f`. Okay I got it: if I create a subclass `D` of `C` and I override `f` in it, calling `D.g` will call `D.f` with `self.f()` but `A.f` with `super().f()`, right?

Comment: Right. `D.g` will resolve to `C.g`, and `super().f`, because the MRO is `[D, C, B, A, object]`, will skip `D.f` and resolve to `A.f`.

Comment: @chepner Okay. If you want to write an answer I will be happy to accept it. So the question was: "In Python, is there a point in calling `super().method()` in a subclass that does not override method?" And the answer is: yes if you want to avoid child implementations (which might be useful after all). If you have a concrete usage it would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @chepner, calling `super().method()` in a subclass that does not override `method` is *not* equivalent to calling `self.method()`. The difference appears in subclasses of that subclass that override `method`.

Compare:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        print("A")

class B:
    pass

class C(B, A):
    def g(self):
        super().f()  # == super(C, self).f(), so lookup starts after C in type(self).__mro__
        print("C")

class D(C):    
    def f(self):
        print("D")

D().g()  # prints A C, since D.__mro__ == (D, C, B, A, object)
```

with:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        print("A")

class B:
    pass

class C(B, A):
    def g(self):
        self.f()  # lookup starts at the beginning in type(self).__mro__
        print("C")

class D(C):
    def f(self):
        print("D")

D().g()  # prints D C, since D.__mro__ == (D, C, B, A, object)
```